How do I get results from one query to influence the second query results
Currently, I have two queries and I would like to condense into one with two SELECT statements. I am using MS Access SQL so that I can create a form later to allow user to add data to search for their criteria using: pathid, ctcode, or casetype. It tells me that I cannot use GROUP_CONCAT() to get achieve a 1 to many result as displayed in my Inner Query picture below (there is only one pathid to one casenumber but many ctcodes for that 1 casenumber).  I have 5 tables patcase, billingcode, internalbillingcode, consultinformation, and specimen. I  believe I need to run two queries to get the information needed. Any Ideas on how to achieve. My inner query is as follows:
THIS CODE ALLOWS ME TO GET pathid, casenumber and ctcode as a one to many result
Inner Query.
For my outer query which is based on the results from the inner query it checks to make sure there is a received date, sign out date, and a turn around time, and allows a user to choose by pathid a no null values:
SELECT DISTINCT
        PATCASE.PATHID,
        PATCASE.CASENUMBER, 
        INTERNALBILLINGCODE.CTCODE
FROM 
     (
       PATCASE 
       INNER JOIN 
       BILLINGCODE 
       ON 
       PATCASE.AAID = BILLINGCODE.RACC_BILL
     ) 
       INNER JOIN 
       INTERNALBILLINGCODE 
       ON 
       BILLINGCODE.CODE = INTERNALBILLINGCODE.IBCODE
WHERE
       PATCASE.PATHID = 'DMP'
AND
       PATCASE.CASENUMBER LIKE 'BMAC3*'
AND
       PATCASE.CASENUMBER LIKE '*118';

SELECT 
       MAX(Nz(PATCASE.PATHID, '')) AS PATHID,
       MAX(Nz(PATCASE.CASENUMBER, '')) AS CASENUMBER,
       MAX(Nz(PAT_INTERNALBILLINGCODE.CTCODE, '')) AS CPTCODE, 
       MAX(Nz(CONSULTMATINFORMATION.CONSULTATNTID, '')) AS CONSULT_CODE, 
       MAX(Nz(CONSULTMATINFORMATION.MATERIALSENDDATE, '')) AS MATERIAL_SEND_DATE,

Format(
        MAX(
            IIF(
                 [RECEIVEDDATE] = 0, 
                 NULL, 
                 DateSerial(Left(Nz([RECEIVEDDATE], '0000'), 4), Mid(Nz([RECEIVEDDATE], '0000'), 5, 2),
                 Right(Nz([RECEIVEDDATE], '00'), 2))
                )
            ),
              'Short Date'
      ) AS RECEIVE_DATE,

Format(
        MAX(
            IIF(
                [SIGNOUTDATE] = -1, 
                NULL, 
                DateSerial(Left(Nz([SIGNOUTDATE], ''), 4), Mid(Nz([SIGNOUTDATE], ''), 5, 2), 
                Right(Nz([SIGNOUTDATE], ''), 2))
               )
            ),
              'Short Date'
      ) AS SIGNOUT_DATE,

Format(
       MAX(
           IIF(
                [RECEIVEDDATE] = 0 OR [SIGNOUTDATE] = -1, 
                NULL, 
                DateDiff('d', 
                DateSerial(Left(Nz([RECEIVEDDATE], ''), 4), Mid(Nz([RECEIVEDDATE], ''), 5, 2),
                Right(Nz([RECEIVEDDATE], ''), 2)), 
                DateSerial(Left(Nz([SIGNOUTDATE], ''), 4), Mid(Nz([SIGNOUTDATE], ''), 5, 2), 
                Right(Nz([SIGNOUTDATE], ''), 2))
              )
           )
        ),
          '0'
  ) AS TURNAROUND_TIME
FROM
     (
       (
         (
           PATCASE
           INNER JOIN BILLINGCODE 
           ON 
           PATCASE.AA_ID = BILLINGCODE.RACC_BILL
         )     
        INNER JOIN INTERNALBILLINGCODE 
        ON 
        BILLINGCODE.CODE = INTERNALBILLINGCODE.IBCODE
       )
      INNER JOIN CONSULTMATINFORMATION 
      ON 
      PATCASE.CASENUMBER = CONSULTMATINFORMATION.CASENUMBER
     )
    INNER JOIN SPECIMEN 
    ON 
    SPECIMEN.CASENO = PATCASE.CASENUMBER 
WHERE 
    PATCASE.PATHID = 'DMP'
    GROUP BY 
    PATCASE.CASENUMBER 
    HAVING 
    MAX(Nz(PATCASE.PATHID, '')) <> '';`

This is what the outer query gives me Outer Query. I like being able to use the inner query to get the pathid and casenumber but it can be changed to outer if need be. Am I going about this the correct way logically, syntactically....
I tried to write inner query as a function but I'm not really sure on how to go about it. I've tried the GROUP_CONCAT() function but throws errors for MS Access in SQL. I am new to access so I am not really sure how all of it works. I see that you can use VBA or MS SQL not sure if I should try one over the other. I did figure out that the languages are not the same. From what I've read the VBA gets called every time where the SQL is already set and ready.

<... OuterQuery> o inner join (<InnerQuery>) i on ?SearchParameter in (i.PathId, i.CaseNumber, i.CTCode) and ?SearchParameter in (o.PathId, o.CaseNumber, o.CTCode)? Because your values don't appear to intersect I can see something as simple as this. I can't remember if this is semi-valid Access syntax and I can't promise any of this is going to be efficient.

@shawnt00 I don't understand what you are trying to say. The queries I'm running aren't intersecting The inner query is just giving me a group_concat() and the outer query is giving me intersecting data from other tables.

I'm saying that none of your path ids look like case numbers or CT codes, etc. Since they don't collide you can get away with a test like that. At the most basic level, I think you want an inner join between the two queries: i.PathId = o.PathId or i.CaseNumber = o.CaseNumber or i.CTCode = o.CTCode) Since I don't keep up with Access very much I can't speak to its current limitations. In the past it has had its share. I don't know what you were attempting with group_concat(). Honestly, you could definitely describe the entire problem in more concrete terms.

would i apply this join i.pathid=o.pathid in the outer SQL. Currently these two queries are not on together how do i name them so that the collide (how do I write them as one single query with a join)?

One options is to create a named query. Another is to define it inline as in select ... from MyTable t inner join (<another query>) q on q.Id = t.Id ... See here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19966/is-it-possible-to-join-derived-tables-to-actual-in-access-2007

Thanks @shawnt00 this lead me to some resolutions
